# Laravel 9 required_if not validating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm using Laravel 9 and Livewire 2.0

I have an integer field called 'new_weight' that should validate required if the boolean checkbox 'stripped' is selected. Although 'stripped' is not selected, it's still validating as required. The validation $rules are being hit because if I remove the rule, it doesn't validate at all.

I also recently noticed that if I die and dump '$this->stripped' when the checkbox is selected, it dumps 'true' to the console and not '1', but if I leave unchecked, it dumps '0'--not sure if this matters.

**edit.php**

```
...
protected $rules = [
    'car_color' => 'required|string',
    'new_weight' => 'required_if:stripped,accepted|integer|min:1|max:999',
];


protected $messages = [
    'car_color' => 'Please enter car color.',
    'new_weight' => 'New Weight Value must be great than 1 but less than 999'
];
...
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
...
<div class="flex items-center h-5">
   <input wire:model.defer="stripped" id="stripped" name="stripped"
          wire:click="updateStripped"
          type="checkbox">
</div>
<div>
<input wire:model.defer="new_weight" id="new_weight" name="new_weight"
       type="text"
       placeholder="New Vehicle Weight in lbs:">
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `new_weight` field had a default `null` value in the database. Once I re-migrated with a default empty value, my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Since stripped itself is not a rule, I would consider using a custom callback to evaluate the stripped input.

```
'new_weight' => [
  Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
    return $request->input('stripped');
  }),
 'integer|min:1|max:999'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too, so I use `Rule::when` like this and get me same result:

```
[Rule::when(this->stripped == 'accepted', 'required|integer|min:1|max:999')]
```

when condition ( this->stripped == 'accepted' ) is true, the rules run

of course if `stripped` is a check box, you must find out what that's return, so first use dd for that, then replace that with `'accepted'` ( I think check box return true and false )

Comment: I figured out my solution.  I realized the `new_weight` field had a default `null` value in the database.  Once I re-migrated with a default empty value, my problem was solved. Could this be the same as your issue?

Comment: Leave your new_weight nullable, according to your edit, checkbox return 0 so change $this->stripped == 'accepted' to $this->stripped != 0